# How to get text of hidden td element using angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

HTML:

```
<td hidden ng-bind="msg.location" id="msg_location"></td>
```

After page loading it seems like:

```
<td hidden ng-bind="msg.location" id="msg_location">/2/</td>
```

i want to get text of td in angularjs. I tried following:

```
angular.element('#msg_location').html()
angular.element('#msg_location').text()
angular.element('#msg_location').innerHTML
```

but all of above soltions returns empty string.
Can anyone help me?

thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try .textContent or .value?

Comment: i tried .value but failure.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent  as per documentation .textContent should do

Comment: why can't you directly use 'msg.location' in angular controller. example - var location = msg.location; I'm assuming msg.location is your model.

Comment: @Anirudh:angular.element('#msg_location').textContent gives undefined.

Comment: @Prasad: msg is an array and am using it in ng-repeat so can not use it for single row as every row contains different value

Answer (score 1):

BECAFULL YOU USE ANGULARJS AND NOT JQUERY. So you just need to set a ng-model like bellow:
**html**

```
<td hidden ng-model='msg.location' ></td>
```

**JS**

```
console.log('DATA IS ',$scope.msg.location);
```